# Context switching kernel threads vs processes

Tags: multithreading, performance, process, operating-system

When I switch between two processes, it takes `x` time.
When I switch between user threads, it takes `y`, `y<x` time. Since there is no real context switch happening, e.g. no TLB gets flushed.

Howevever, when I switch between two kernel threads, would this `z` be faster than `x`?

Comment: This is entirely system dependent. Some systems do not even have kernel threads.

Comment: assuming the system has kernel threads

Comment: It's still system dependent. You need more information.

Comment: A kernel process is just-like user process expect for it has elevated privileges (crudely, mode bit is set to high). So I think switching a kernel thread would take the comparable time with respect to switching a user thread and would sure be faster than switching user programs